# What exactly happens when we write if(mp.find()==mp.end())

Tags: c++, hashmap, iterator

I'm currently learning hashmap, I'm facing trouble understanding the iterators, while using it in if statements.

For example,

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;
  mymap['a']=50;
  mymap['b']=100;
  mymap['c']=150;
  mymap['d']=200;

  it = mymap.find('d');
  if (it == mymap.end())
    mymap.erase (it);
  if (it != mymap.end())
    mymap.erase (it);
}
```

I am able to understand what happens in the **second** if statement. Can anyone explain what exactly does the **first** if statement will do? When I tried to erase the value of d it does nothing. Can someone explain the difference between the two if statements?

Comment: `if (it == mymap.end()) mymap.erase (it);` has undefined behavior.  You are not allowed to erase `end()`

Comment: I mean technically, since both `if` statements do the same thing (and are inverse booleans), the code is logically equivalent to `mymap.erase(it);`.

Comment: _"When I tried to erase the value of d it does nothing"_  How did you determine that nothing was done?

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know what the `end` iterator is in general? Do you know what `find` returns?

Comment: An iterator is an "object" (not necessarily a pointer) that traverses your data structure. The end() iterator represents a position "one beyond" the last element in your datastructure (sometimes a guard position) and thus is not part of your datastructure (and does not refer to anything valid). Trying to do something with the end() iterator (other then comparing) is a programming error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`std::map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used as a value for pos.

Since the below part of the code fails to comply with the above

```
if (it == mymap.end())
    mymap.erase (it);
```

the program will have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in case `it == mymap.end()` - which means that it could do just about anything, including nothing or crashing. Avoid undefined behavior like the plague.

---

The other part is the correct way to do it. Make sure that `it` is *not* the `end()` iterator before using it to erase an element.

```
if (it != mymap.end())
    mymap.erase (it);
```

---

> Can someone explain the difference between the two if statements?

`it = mymap.find('d');` searches for `'d'` in the `map`. If `'d'` is found, it returns an iterator to the place in the map where the *key* `'d'` was found. If `'d'` is *not* found, it returns the `end()` iterator. The `end()` iterator in all standard containers (possible exception: `basic_string`), and even plain arrays, isn't dereferenceable. Using an array to illustrate:

```
int a[] = {7,8,9};
```

Memory layout:

```
addr   a+0 a+1 a+2 a+3
      +---+---+---+---
value | 7 | 8 | 9 | (out of bounds)
      +---+---+---+---
        ^           ^
        |           |
std::begin(a)   std::end(a)
```

The `end()` iterator for a plain array points one step after the last element and dereferencing it would mean that you peek out of bounds, with undefined behavior as a result. It's similar for `map`s, only that the memory layout isn't as simple as for plain arrays.

The difference between the two `if` statements is therefore that one makes sure that the iterator *can* be deferenced before using it to `erase` - and the other makes sure that the iterator is not an iterator that should be deferenced (or used with `erase`), before using it with `erase` anyway.